# Switched favicons for certain sites in inbox, achievements, and community tabs

Tags: bug, global-inbox, achievements-dialog, favicon, tor

When I click on my inbox or on the achievements button, it appears that the icon for Meta.SE has been switched with the one for Stack Apps; it's basically displaying the Stack Apps favicon even for rep changes/messages on Meta.SE.

It's doing the same thing by switching the favicon for Software Engineering with Skeptics.

(I'm using Tor, and this only happens on Tor.)

Screenshots:

| Achievements | Inbox |
| --- | --- |
| [image: achievements] | [image: inbox] |

The issue also appears on the icons in the *Communities* dialog:

[image: Communities]

Weird.

Comment: @CDR Yup. Movies & TV is now Personal Finance & Money in HNQ.

Comment: See [Sites' icons appear shifted / wrong sites' icons are appearing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/390757/334566)

Comment: This problem existed more generally a couple/few days ago when a new site graduated from private beta. The issue is almost certainly caching somewhere along the path from which you get SE content and/or resources (e.g., like the sprite sheet or CSS). Given that this has, at this point, been resolved for most people, I'd recommend that you investigate in your browser from where such resources are being obtained and the version of the resource which you are receiving. Clear any caches which you're able to clear.

Comment: When I first saw this I was like 'Did they migrate my question to Stack Apps for some bizarre reason? I don't see why they would.' And then I was like 'Uh... what?'